# How do I replace the values in a column given that I dont want to change some values in the column?

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ball | 1 | Yes |
| Paper | 2 | No |
| Shoes | 10 | No |
| Pen | 4 | Yes |
| Glue | 1 | No |

Given that I have column A and column B in a dataframe. Column C is the output I'm looking for.
Note that I have thousands of rows in the dataframe.

```
conditions = [(df['Column A'] == 'Ball'), 
              (df['Column A'] == 'Paper') | (df['Column A'] == 'Shoes'),
              (df['Column B'] == 1),
              (df['Column B'] >= 1)
             ]

outcomes = ['Yes', 'No', 'No', "Yes"]

df['Column C'] = np.select(conditions, outcomes, default=0)
```

I tried the code above and I got **TypeError: 'Series' object is not callable** due to condition 3 and 4.

Then I tried to remove the third and fourth condition and add new code.

```
df['Publish to Data Model'] = np.where(df['Count'] == 1, 'No', 'Yes')
```

However, it overwrites the earlier values that I got from column C.

Main question is how do I write the statements given that I need to refer to 2 different columns without replacing the first value that I found?

Comment: You are missing a comma in conditions array.

Comment: What is the 'Data Field' column? Why does the line with Pen get Yes? Explain in more detail how to get Column C.

Answer (score -1):

```
conditions = [(df['Column A'] == 'Ball'), 
              (df['Column A'] == 'Paper') | (df['Data Field'] == 'Shoes'),
              (df['Column B'] == 1),
              (df['Column B'] >= 1)
             ]

outcomes = ['Yes', 'No', 'No', "Yes"]

df['Column C'] = np.select(conditions, outcomes, default=0)
```